# Asymptotic behavior of polynomials

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, algorithms, asymptotics

The following question is taken from [Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) by CLRS, Chapter $3.$

> Let 
>   $$p(n) = \sum_{i=0}^d a_i n^i,$$
>   where $a_d>0,$ be a degree-$d$ polynomial in $n$, and let $k$ be a constant. Use the definitions of the asymptotic notations to prove the following properties.
>
> a. If $k\geq d,$ then $p(n)= O(n^k).$
>
> b. If $k\leq d,$ then $p(n)= \Omega(n^k).$
>
> c. If $k =  d,$ then $p(n)= \Theta(n^k).$
>
> d. If $k> d,$ then $p(n)= o(n^k).$
>
> a. If $k< d,$ then $p(n)= \omega(n^k).$

My attempt:

From exercise $3.1$-$1$ in the same chapter, we have proven that for asymptotically nonnegative function $f(n)$ and $g(n),$ 
$$max(f(n),g(n)) = \Theta(f(n)+g(n)).$$
So we have 
$$\Theta(f(n)+g(n)) = \Theta(max(f(n),g(n))).$$
It follows that 
$$p(n) = \Theta(p(n)) = \Theta\left( \sum_{i=0}^d a_i n^i \right) = \Theta(n^d).$$
So all parts (a)-(e) follow.

Is my attempt above correct?

Answer (score 3):

You are using:

$\displaystyle 0<\lim\limits_{n\to a}\inf\left|\frac{\max(f(n),g(n))}{f(n)+g(n)}\right|\leq\lim\limits_{n\to a}\sup\left|\frac{\max(f(n),g(n))}{f(n)+g(n)}\right|<\infty~$

We get a problem, if $~f~$ and $~g~$ are polynomials and at least one is no constant:

$\max(f(n),g(n))=~\infty~$

It's impossible to use your argumentation, it's better to use the definitions:

a. $\displaystyle ~p(n)= O(n^k) :~~\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup\left|\frac{p(n)}{n^k}\right|<\infty$

b. $\displaystyle ~p(n)= \Omega(n^k) :~~\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\inf\left|\frac{p(n)}{n^k}\right|>0~$

c. $\displaystyle ~p(n)= \Theta(n^k) :~~0<\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\inf\left|\frac{p(n)}{n^k}\right|\leq\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup\left|\frac{p(n)}{n^k}\right|<\infty~$ , $~$it's $~$a.$~$ and $~$b.

d. $\displaystyle ~p(n)= o(n^k) :~~\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{p(n)}{n^k}\right|= 0$

e. $\displaystyle ~p(n)= \omega(n^k) :~~\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{p(n)}{n^k}\right|= \infty$

Comment: Is the limsup and liminf a characterization for big o notation?

Comment: @Idonknow: Yes, it is so (it's about accuracy).

Comment: @Idonknow: I am very sorry, I first thought about functions which have a maximum. But that's impossible if you use polynomials, we have $n\to\infty$ and therefore unlimited functions, no *global* maximum exists.

Comment: @Idonknow : I try to understand what your intension was to use $\max$ . Now I think, it's: If we assume, that $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are polynomials, you perhaps thought about something like $k=\max(degree(f(n)),degree(g(n)))$ and this explains your last line $p(n)=...$ .

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you think about your definitions a bit.

Consider the function in the sum: $\sum_{i=0}^d{a_i n^i} = a_d n^d + a_{d-1} n^{d-1} + a_{d-2}n^{d-2} + \dots$

Now, the question told you that the function is a polynomial in $n$.  Believe it or not, that means that only $n$ really matters in asymptotic notation.

Going back to our function:

$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^d{a_i n^i} &= a_d n^d + \dots \\
                      &=   \Theta{n^d} \\
                      &=   O(n^{d+1}) \\
                      &=   O(n^{d} \\
                      &=   o(n^{d+1}) \\
                      &\ne o(n^d) \\
                      &=   \omega(n^{d-1}) \\
                      &\ne \omega(n^d) \\
                      &=   \Omega(n^{d-1}) \\
                      &=   \Omega(n^d)
\end{align}$

I hope this helps.  Keep looking at the definitions, and think that they're all really about $n$ and that they're functions of $n$, polynomials of $n$.

Just add comments below if you need more help.

Comment: I understand your solution. But my question is about whether my approach above is valid or not.

Comment: I think that you'd have to use the properties of polynomials in the proof.  In other words, I think that you have to use what $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are in the proof.